# How can I release my font under SIL font license or Appache font license

Tags: fonts, typography, font-recommendation, font-design, font-licensing

I made fonts for logo design 3 weeks ago and I want to give it to others so they can use it for free.

Would you please tell me the process how to do it?

Comment: See https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ofl#5667e9e4 - look at the section titled "Using the OFL".

Comment: One caveat: You must have started from a clean board to zero potential copyright problems. If you have started from a non 100% free font, say taken something from Linotype or Adobe repertoire and replaced only the glyphs with your own shapes you are in a weak position if Linotype or Adobe decides to take your money. Designing good letter shapes is only a part of creating a computer font. The underlying placement and sizing rules in font file need also much work if one aims good results, so it's tempting to use something already available and think "who cares, it's invisible". But it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Great choice! You just put it up on Github and say it's released under the OFL. (I'm not an expert but get the impression OFL is better than Apache for fonts.)